# How to capture a group to the next first group?

Tags: java, regex

Have a string :

station:C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,team:C5TQ5,C3TQ1,C5TQ1,test:value,...

When I get my third group, I want to get until the first next group.

My regex :

```
/(\w+?)(:)(.*)/g
```

I expect :

station (group1)
: (group2)
C1,C2,C3,C4,C5 (group3)

team (group1)
: (group2)
C5TQ5,C3TQ1,C5TQ1 (group3)

test (group1)
: (group2)
value (group3)

Etc.

Comment: *It's unclear what you're asking. (Flag)* By this I mean that we don't know enough about the stations, the groups, and how we are supposed to know how to pair them.

Comment: The problem is that `.*` matches all until line end.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking for regex from Java and not from JavaScript (Java doesn't use `/regex/flags` syntax).

Comment: @FailingCoder It seems to be clear because Samuel Philipp and Pshemo understood my problem. But thank you for your answer :)

Comment: @Pshemo Yep, it was for java purpose. My real regex is :
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+?)(:)(.*)"). But I use https://regex101.com/ to check my regex. This is the reason why my regex looks like JavaScript :) Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
(\w+)(:)(.*?)(?=,\w+:|,?$)
```

This does a positive lookahead until the next group is found or the end of the string is reached.

The result will be this:

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you are looking for regex like `(\w+)(:)(\w+(,(?![^,]+:)\w+)*)` where

1. `(\w+)` places "key" in group 1
2. `(:)` places colon in group 2
3. `((\w+)(,(?![^,]+:)\w+)*)` places in group 3 one alphanumeric word `\w+` optionally followed by zero or more words separated by comma.

   - With [negative look ahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?![^,]+:)` we are ensuring that accepted word (serie of non-comma characters) can't be followed by colon.

Demo:

```
String data = "station:C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,team:C5TQ5,C3TQ1,C5TQ1,test:value";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)(:)(\\w+(,(?![^,]+:)\\w+)*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
while (m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
    System.out.println(m.group(3));
    System.out.println("===");
}
```

Output:

```
station
:
C1,C2,C3,C4,C5
===
team
:
C5TQ5,C3TQ1,C5TQ1
===
test
:
value
===
```